# Time Delay until next message sent from Discord Bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

In the Discord bot I'm creating, I'd like to make it so that the bot waits lets say 60 seconds before sending another reply to the same command or "includes" word. For instance, if someone says `ping` below, I want the bot to wait a minute until the next one is sent. I do not want the bot to hold it and put it into a queue or anything of that sort, I just want it to ignore the command for a minute until the next one happens.

```js
if (message.content.includes("ping")) {
    message.reply("pong!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would want to make a boolean variable and use `setTimeout`.

The global function `setTimeout` waits for the provided amount of milliseconds, in this case 60000 (60 seconds), then changes the variable to `true` again so it can be run.

```js
var pingEnabled = true;

if (ping command run && pingEnabled) {
    reply("Pong!");
    pingEnabled = false;
    setTimeout(() => { pingEnabled = true }, 60000);
}
```

*most of this is pseudocode and you may need to adapt it to your situation.*